# Creating paths from a map

Tags: elixir

I've got such a problem and don't really know how to properly work this out. I need to create a paths list of a given map. The paths list should consist of tuples, including a list of keys leading to the given value and the value itself, as in example below.

Example input:

```
%{
  foo: %{
    bar: %{
      value: "y"
    },
    car: %{
      value: "x"
    }
  },
  second: "level"
}
```

Example output:

```
[
 { [:foo, :bar, :value], "y" },
 { [:foo, :car, :value], "x" },
 { [:second], "level"}
]
```

The way I tried to implement it is to use recursive function with `Enum.reduce()/3`, going through all the keys and values in the map.

```
def reduce_map(paths_map, nest) do
  Enum.reduce(paths_map, nest, fn {key, val}, acc ->
    case typeof(val) do
     "map" ->
        acc ++ [reduce_map(val, [key])]
      _ ->
        acc ++ [key]
    end
  end)
end
```

I've got the feeling that this is the right direction to solve this, but I still can't figure out how to move further from this point. The output of this function with given above example is:

```
[[:foo, [:bar, :value], [:car, :value]], :second]
```

I hope someone can help me solve this problem :) Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right direction indeed. Notice, however that you're passing `val` to the recursive function call, but you're not including it in the result when `val` is not a map.

Also, to avoid things like nested keys being grouped under the parent, like it seems to have happened in your result, you could probably use an extra argument to keep track of the keys in the path up to a certain key in nested maps.

Here's a solution that works using what I just mentioned, but it was drafted pretty quickly and I'm sure it's rather naive and can be improved in many ways:

```rb
defmodule Test do                                                
  def reduce(map, paths, accumulated_paths) do                    
    Enum.reduce(map, paths, fn {key, val}, acc when is_map(val) ->
        acc ++ [reduce(val, paths, accumulated_paths ++ [key])]   
      {key, val}, acc ->                                          
        acc ++ [{accumulated_paths ++ [key], val}]                
    end)
  end
end
```

And then in iex:

```rb
iex> m = %{
...>   foo: %{
...>     bar: %{
...>       value: "y"
...>     },
...>     car: %{
...>       value: "x"
...>     }
...>   },
...>   second: "level"
...> }
%{foo: %{bar: %{value: "y"}, car: %{value: "x"}}, second: "level"}
iex> Test.reduce(m, [], []) |> List.flatten()
[{[:foo, :bar, :value], "y"}, {[:foo, :car, :value], "x"}, {[:second], "level"}]
```

As you may see, it produces the expected result, but, for instance, it requires a call to `List.flatten` because nested lists are added

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the library to deeply iterate nested structs, [`Iteraptor`](https://hexdocs.pm/iteraptor/Iteraptor.html#each/3-examples).

If you are OK with 3rd-parties, it’d be as easy as:

```rb
Iteraptor.each(input, &IO.inspect/1)

{[:foo, :bar, :value], "y"}
{[:foo, :car, :value], "x"}
{[:second], "level"}

#⇒ %{foo: %{bar: %{value: "y"}, car: %{value: "x"}},
#    second: "level"}
```

It’s OSS, so you might check the source for more insights. Also, it provides `map/2`, `reduce/3`, etc.

Comment: That's pretty useful!

Comment: Well, honestly I quit using it myself, mostly because I came to conclusion that it is always better to either restructure the input, or use `Access`. But thank you, I am glad you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

I find it difficult to reason over `Enum.reduce` when you start to have nesting, and often end up just using basic functions with recursion for things like this:

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def reduce_map(tree) do
    tree |> reduce_map([]) |> List.flatten()
  end

  def reduce_map(tree, path) when is_map(tree) do
    for {k, v} <- tree, do: reduce_map(v, [k | path])
  end

  def reduce_map(value, path), do: {Enum.reverse(path), value}
end
```

IEx:

```elixir
iex(1)> Example.reduce_map(%{foo: %{bar: %{value: "y"}, car: %{value: "x"}}, second: "level"})
[{[:foo, :bar, :value], "y"}, {[:foo, :car, :value], "x"}, {[:second], "level"}]
```